# Open folder in current explorer window using batch

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch, cmd.exe

I am trying to open a folder using batch, but want to open the folder in the current explorer window, not in a new one. The delay caused by having to run explorer again vs just navigating is annoying. Is there any way to do this?

[For example, I want this to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph7zT.gif). 
[image]

[Not this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWExc.gif)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, I submitted an edit and embedded your animated gifs into the post, saving readers from clicking your preserved links. I hope you find the answer to this compelling question.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer.exe doesnt lend itself to the type of smooth interaction that you desire. The below commands (see code below) can help you achieve "kind of" what you requested but wont look very nice.
The code would kill the old Explorer process by process id and would be severely limited, because it would only work if there was only one process.

The best you can do with Explorer.exe is to open a specific folder with a file selected (its in focus). This sounds promising and makes it seem more could be done. But its not as versatile as this capability would suggest. So with these references from Microsoft/SS64 (at the bottom of this article), you know you cant change directories from the currently open Explorer process. Only kill and open a new one.

```
REM Kill explorer without having to restart it.
wmic process where "ProcessID='11972'" CALL Terminate

REM Kill/restart Explorer
TaskKill /F /FI "ImageName eq "Explorer.exe"
Explorer
```

Your best bet if you really want to achieve your aim is to use a Windows Shell replacement or some automation software like AutoIT. You can look up the topic Windows shell replacement and find lots of apps that have other features
missing from Windows, a popular topic, or maybe one of these is exactly what your looking for.

If your a programmer you could probably achieve this see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programmatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer

Undocumented Explorer commands
From Microsoft       https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/130510/command-line-switches-for-windows-explorer

SS64 Explorer.exe    https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html